# Renaming folders with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to be able to often renaming multiple folders in ASP. None of the methods that I've found are working for me. Here is the current method that I am trying-

```
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FS.MoveFolder "/images/715", "/images/V14"
```

This, as well as others that I've tried, always gives me a "path not found" error. I know that the directory that the script is in has these folders in it because I've been renaming them manually. Does the script need to know the full path? What if I don't know what the full path may be?

**Update:**

The script runs in a directory named "/ifp". I also tried this, with and without the "/ifp" and both forward and back slashes, and it also gave path not found. Once this works on my testing server I send it to the guy with the production server so I can't use any static directory names other than the "/images/????"

```
Dim sCurPath
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
FS.MoveFolder sCurPath & "\ifp\images\715", sCurPath & "\ifp\images\V14"
```

Comment: You *really* have a top level directory `/images`? Perhaps the error is that you're using absolute paths here.

Answer (score 3):

Use absolute paths (`C:\images\715`). It would look like this:

```
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FS.MoveFolder "C:\images\715", "C:\images\V14"
```

If you are using a -nix system then keep in mind that the first `/` is the root directory - ensure you do indeed have an images folder in the root directory path.

Also note that in order to rename the folder there cannot be trailing `\`'s after the folder names and the script must be run on the local machine.

If you keep getting path errors, you're passing it incorrectly somehow. Build in some error checking to see what is going wrong:

```
Dim tmpPath = "\ifp\images\715"
Dim newPath = "\ifp\images\V14"

If FS.FolderExists(sCurPath & tmpPath) Then
    Response.Write("The folder exists.")
    FS.MoveFolder sCurPath & tmpPath, sCurPath & newPath
Else
    Response.Write("The folder " & sCurPath & tmpPath & " does not exist.")
End If
```

Comment: See what I added above. The folder "/715" has no sub folders.

Comment: Windows understands the forward slash as a path delimiter, that can't be the problem.

Comment: I get - Permission_denied:_'MsgBox' OK, I changed that to response.write and now I get "The folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\ifp\images\715 does not exist" but it's still there.

Comment: check that path carefully, if it says it does not exist - it doesn't. Unless you're doing something you're not telling me, like connecting remotely to another system and using this.

Comment: This is running on a web server. Does that make a difference? Why does my sCurPath not know that it's running in the /ifp directory?

Comment: When I look in the file manager it's also in the httpdocs folder so sCurPath is definetely not returning what I need.

Comment: I found that when is used this it worked - sCurPath = Server.MapPath("\ifp") - with tmpPath = "\images\715" and newPath = "\images\V14", but I guess I still need to know what folder the program will be run in.

Comment: `[comment 1/2]` The reason it's finding `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\...` is because sCurPath is set to `"."`, which in Windows means "Current directory". The default current directory is your PATH environment variable, which will depend on the context of the script you're running as. If you're on 64 bit Windows, running the script as a 32 bit script (which is the default if you're using NT Authority\SYSTEM), .\ is effectively the same as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. That same script, run as a 64 bit process, would print out to `C:\Windows\System32`. If you were running it as a user...

Comment: `[comment 2/2]` account, it would be `C:\Users\<username>`. And because those paths are relative, your script will never find the correct path for the folder you're trying to rename. Just about the only way to get it to point to a hard path is to either use an environment variable such as `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\...`, or just hard-code the path `C:\inetpub\...`. Your script is operating exactly as it was intended.